# Unable to convert NSString to NSdate format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to convert my input string to particular `NSDate` format,

Here is the code I have tried.

```
NSString * result;
NSDate * resultDate;

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:maxUpcomingDateString];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormat1.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MMM/dd"];

NSLog(@"maxUpcomingDateString %@",maxUpcomingDateString)
NSDate *d=[dateFormat1 dateFromString:maxUpcomingDateString];

result = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date];
resultDate=[dateFormat1 dateFromString:result];

NSLog(@"max1 date upcoming %@",result);
NSLog(@"max2 date upcoming %@", resultDate);
```

Output of my log shows:

```
maxUpcomingDateString 10 January 2017
max1 date upcoming 2017/Jan/10
max2 date upcoming (null)
```

I want the output date in the form of `2017/Jan/10`. When I try to log the string it shows me the correct output but when I convert it back to `NSDate` it shows null.

Comment: Why are you converting it back to an NSDate object? You already have the NSDate object for that date string.

Comment: What's the point of the `d` variable? It won't work and it seems to be unused anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**nsstring to nsdate**

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

**nsdate to nsstring**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

add this code on dateFormat

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
```

It will solve the problem.

Comment: where do i write this line?

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

Answer (score -1):

Add this code after allocating the dateFormat object.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
```